# Simple Git question - try to push repository to Azure-DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops

I try to push git repository to Azure Repos  using this command `git push -u origin --all`, it asks for Password for 'https://itzikgb0643@dev.azure.com'.

Which password should I enter?
I already set SSH key and uploaded it to Azure DevOps server.

Comment: Check git remote using `git remote -v ` command and make sure you have cloned using HTTPS or SSH.

Answer (score 1):

You seems to have cloned the repo using https url and not the ssh one. Check the url in **config** file inside **.git** folder. 
You have to enter your Azure DevOps password to push the code.

Answer (score 0):

Setting an SSH key would not change anything when using an... HTTPS URL.

In your case, since you are using an HTTPS URL, the password requested would be the `itzikgb0643` account password on `dev.azure.com`.

For SSH, see "[Azure/ Use SSH key authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=current-page)".

An SSH URL would look like: `git@ssh.dev.azure.com:...`